# Need SQL query to get list of all concurrent program other than sysadmin program

Tags: database, oracle, plsql, oracle-ebs

I am trying to generate a list of all concurrent programs except sysadmin programs in Oracle EBS R12.1. Could you please share the query if you have worked on such a requirement? TIA.

Comment: What have you tried, and what makes you think it is not correct?

Answer (score 0):

You can get a list of all programs and executables from the [FND Concurrent Programs and Executables](https://www.enginatics.com/reports/fnd-concurrent-programs-and-executables/) blitz report.

If you are looking for concurrent requests (not just program definitions), then there is report [FND Concurrent Requests](https://www.enginatics.com/reports/fnd-concurrent-requests/)

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is looking for the related SQL query, here is one for eBS R11.5.9 that should also work on R12 :

```sql
SELECT FND_APPLICATION.APPLICATION_SHORT_NAME,
       FND_CONCURRENT_PROGRAMS.CONCURRENT_PROGRAM_ID,
       FND_CONCURRENT_PROGRAMS.CONCURRENT_PROGRAM_NAME,
       FND_CONCURRENT_PROGRAMS.CREATION_DATE
  FROM FND_CONCURRENT_PROGRAMS JOIN FND_APPLICATION ON FND_APPLICATION.APPLICATION_ID = FND_CONCURRENT_PROGRAMS.APPLICATION_ID 
                                                   AND FND_APPLICATION.APPLICATION_SHORT_NAME != 'SYSADMIN'
 ORDER BY FND_CONCURRENT_PROGRAMS.CREATION_DATE;
```

I guess that OP was looking more for user defined concurrent programs, so it should also filter all standard eBS concurrent programs. As user defined programs are generally on a custom application, that can be done by joining with applications having a NULL product code :

```sql
SELECT FND_APPLICATION.APPLICATION_SHORT_NAME,
       FND_CONCURRENT_PROGRAMS.CONCURRENT_PROGRAM_ID,
       FND_CONCURRENT_PROGRAMS.CONCURRENT_PROGRAM_NAME,
       FND_CONCURRENT_PROGRAMS.CREATION_DATE
  FROM FND_CONCURRENT_PROGRAMS JOIN FND_APPLICATION ON FND_APPLICATION.APPLICATION_ID = FND_CONCURRENT_PROGRAMS.APPLICATION_ID 
                                                   AND FND_APPLICATION.PRODUCT_CODE IS NULL
 ORDER BY FND_CONCURRENT_PROGRAMS.CREATION_DATE;
```